# R I cannot select specific values from a Variable that contains data like "01 1 5"

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, sqldf

I have a dataframe like:

```
Tabla
IDrel ID_Sector
1     01 1 02
2     01 1 06
3     01SC
```

The `ID_Sector` is a factor, but I can transform it to character and
I want to filter the data, by selecting only some `ID_Sector`s.

I proved with

```
Tabla_1 <- sqldf("SELECT *
                 FROM Tabla
                 WHERE ID_Sector = '01SC'")
```

and gives me a dataframe with 0 observations

I proved also with:

```
Tabla_1 <- subset(Tabla, ID_Sector == "01 1")
```

and also gives me 0 observations.

I can with the SQLDF select an observation like "obs one", but I can`t make it with something like "1 0 1".

Comment: Try with `trimws` i..e `subset(Tabla, trimws(ID_Sector) == "01 1")` assuming that it is a `character` class column

Comment: You could also use sql like command.

Comment: thanks but it gives me the same number of observations than the original table, as if no filter were applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but does this do it for you?

```
library(dplyr)

Tabla <- data.frame(IDrel = 1:3, ID_Sector = as.factor(c("01 01 02", "01 01 06","01SC")))
```

And this gives:

```
Tabla

  IDrel ID_Sector
1     1  01 01 02
2     2  01 01 06
3     3      01SC
```

You can then change that to a character string, before obtaining the item in question:

```
Tabla$ID_Sector <- as.character(Tabla$ID_Sector)

Example <- Tabla %>% 
  filter(ID_Sector == "01SC")
```

This gives:

```
Example

  IDrel ID_Sector
1     3      01SC
```

Here's hoping that this helps you.

If not, then it sounds like you'll need to do some RegEx work on the string in question. For this, assuming that you're after the last word of this string, I'd use `mutate` from dplyr and `word` from stringr:

```
Tabla1 <- Tabla %>% 
  mutate(ID_Sector_LastWord = word(ID_Sector,start = -1))

Tabla

  IDrel ID_Sector ID_Sector_LastWord
1     1  01 01 02                 02
2     2  01 01 06                 06
3     3      01SC               01SC
```

You could then filter on `ID_Sector_LastWord`.